# How can disable open color palet when i click on <input type="color">?

Tags: html, input

i Have the input:

```
<input type="color">
```

And when i click on it automaticaly open the windows color palet, how can disabled this? For example:

```
<input type="color" colorpallet="disable"> ?
```

Comment: Do you want to disable the field altogether or just stop the color palette from appearing? If the former, then `<input type="color" disabled>` but then no one can use it until you remove that attribute. If the latter, offer some detail on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes i want just stop the color palette from appearing

Comment: Then no, not in a cross-browser standards-compliant way. Tell us what you are trying to do or just don't use that element.

Comment: Ok! I want use the bootstrap color picker with <input type="color"> and not with <input type="text"> please don't ask me why, that i want to do. But when i write in html <input type="color"> and click on it show the bootstrap color picker and chrome picker both. how can stop this?

Comment: Ah, then I am out. I do not use Bootstrap. Check the documentation or look for a plug-in.

Comment: ok thenk you very match!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

`<input type="color" disabled></input>`

OR

```
document.getElementById("myColor").disabled = true;
```

These are the way to disable inputs in html. If you are looking for bootstrap color picker with `<input type="color">` here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MadanBhandari/ztcc4kd2/).

Comment: No this is very wrong because disable and the bootstrap colorpicker

Comment: it's the way to disable inputs in html

Comment: Yes but with the same way disable and the bootstrap colorpicker we need other way

Comment: you mean, you want to use bootstrap color picker instead of default one ??

Comment: check added fiddle link

Comment: Oh yes perfect that i need

Comment: then enjoy buddy :)